# Is there any difference between paid and unpaid versions of elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation

I am user of Ubuntu. I just want to decide install elementary OS.

When I go to the [official site](https://elementary.io/) the actual size showing is 909 MB, but the downloaded file with $0 shows 867 MB. Why?

Is there any difference between downloading with and without money?

Comment: Your title doesn't fit to your question.

Comment: Here you are asking few questions not a single one. Many of your Qs will be answered at ^ post, and " no download happened"--I don't think it is __on-topic__,  try: Enter __0__ amount and try download

Comment: thank you elementaryOS. I paid and needed to do a second download. I paid $0 the second time and it is exactly the same ISO. Thanks for being honest elementaryOS. Not many organisations are honest anymore!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, there is absolutely no difference between paid and unpaid downloads. They link to identical ISO files.**

To answer your first question, yes, elementary OS *is* open source. Most of the code can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/elementary). Even the [elementary.io](https://elementary.io) website itself [is open source](https://github.com/elementary/mvp).

To answer your second question, you're making a mistake by confusing MB with MiB. It's a pretty common error. Here's the difference:

1. Decimal: 1 MB = 1000 KB
2. Binary: 1 MiB = 1024 KiB

The website itself displays the size in MB, while your application actually displays the size in MiB. The size is the same, the standard used to display it is not.

Here's an example. I have downloaded the `.iso` file using qBittorrent. Then, I checked its size using both qBittorrent and Pantheon Files. Here's what I got:

[image: difference between MB and MiB]

Notice how they are displaying the different size even though they are actually displaying the size of the same file.

Comment: impressive explanation =)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, elementary OS is completly Open Source. Most projects are listed [here](https://github.com/elementary).

The iso is the same regardless you pay something or not.

You can verify the iso. See this [site](https://elementary.io/de/docs/installation#verify-your-download).

Comment: thanks =)..then why the difference in file size mentioned and downloading iso

Answer (score 5):

There is no special version of elementary OS only for paying users (and there will never be one). The payment is a pay-what-you-want thing which allows you to pay $0. Your payment is entirely voluntary to support the development of elementary OS. Just type in $0 in the "custom amount" box.

Therefore, if you paid and didn't get a download, re-try it with $0. It will not make any difference. However you might consider to open a bug report at [elementary.io's GitHub page](https://github.com/elementary/mvp) to let the developers know there is something wrong with the paid download.

Answer (score 2):

You are of course not required to pay. If you did the devs will surely appreciate though.

Your question gives almost no details on what problem you are facing. If you did not see the window with the links to download the torrent files, you can just go to https://elementary.io, enter $0 and click the "Download" button